# My "{0}" placeholders aren't working. Is there any way to fix them

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi! What is your name?");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Hi {0} how are you? <Please write 'Good' or 'Bad'>", name);

            string howAre = Console.ReadLine();

            if (howAre == "Good")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Excellent!");
                Console.WriteLine("<Press Any Key To Continue>");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else if (howAre == "Bad")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Don't {0} worry everyone always had a bad day :) " + name);
                Console.WriteLine("<Press Any Key To Continue>");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else
            { 
                Console.WriteLine("<Please write 'Good' or 'Bad'> ");
                Console.WriteLine("<Press Any Key To Return>");
                Console.ReadKey();
                return;
            }
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: "aren't working" is _not_ a useful error description! _What exactly_ happens, what did you expect instead? In the second last `else` block, you don't provide any argument that should replace `{0}`. You probably meant `Console.WriteLine("Don't {0} worry everyone always had a bad day :) ", name);`, not `+ name)`.

Comment: Theres a `+` instead of a `,` inside the `else if (howAre == "Bad")`

Comment: One part of posting good questions is to trim down your code to the smallest possible piece that shows the failure because then there's less room for confusion for the people who are looking at the code.  (As a bonus, it will often help you identify the issue yourself, which is always a victory.)

Comment: The first one does work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the line

```
Console.WriteLine("Don't {0} worry everyone always had a bad day :) " + name)
```

To

```
Console.WriteLine("Don't {0} worry everyone always had a bad day :) ", name)
```

Comment: Some extra input: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting

Answer (score 3):

In C#6 onwards you can use string interpolation, which is more readable and economical:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Don't worry {name} everyone always had a bad day :)");
```

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned the dollar sign.

Comment: How have I never heard about this until now? This changes everything!

Answer (score 2):

You need to change this line:

```
Console.WriteLine("Don't {0} worry everyone always had a bad day :) " + name);
```

To This:

```
Console.WriteLine("Don't {0} worry everyone always had a bad day :) ", name);
```

**Why?**

Because you use the `+` sign and that just prints the `string name` behind the `Console.writeline`.

If you change it to `, name` it will print out your `string name` at the position of the `{0}`

Answer (score 1):

Just adding some input on another way you can do this without the {0} is using string interpolation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Example:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Don't {name} worry everyone always had a bad day");
```